# What to do with subscription-manager in a Red Hat Network Satellite environment?

Tags: redhat, rhel5, satellite, rhn

Yum commands all give the following error message:

```
Unable to read consumer identity
```

It seems however that subscription-manager plugin should be disabled if I use RHN/Satellite?

What to do after registering the server with RHN Satellite with this command?

```
rhnreg_ks --serverUrl=http://YourSpacewalk.example.org/XMLRPC --activationkey=<key-with-rhel-custom-channel>.
```

Should I manually disable the Yum subscription-manager plugin on all servers? I am not supposed to subscribe with subscription-manager either, right?

```
yum repolist
Loaded plugins: katello, product-id, rhnplugin, security, subscription-manager
Updating certificate-based repositories.
Unable to read consumer identity
repo id                                                                               repo name                                                                                                          status
rhel-x86_64-server-5                                                                  Red Hat Enterprise Linux (v. 5 for 64-bit x86_64)                                                                  13,371
repolist: 13,287

subscription-manager list
+-------------------------------------------+
    Installed Product Status
+-------------------------------------------+
ProductName:            Red Hat Enterprise Linux Server
Version:                5.8                      
Arch:                   x86_64                   
Status:                 Not Subscribed           
Starts:                 None                     
Expires:                None
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're right, you need to use the old "rhnplugin" to talk to RHN Classic or RHN Satellite.

The "Unable to read consumer identity" message is harmless, it's just the "subscription-manager" plugin saying the system isn't registered via RHSM.

You can disable the "subscription-manager" plugin on your clients if you like.